# Want to get users input during call

Tags: android

I want to achieve the following in android.

When userA make call to userB.
when userB press any key during call on number pad then userA can get notification about users selected button.

Is it possible?

Comment: No, It is not possible, the reason is you need a special kind of device to read the user input. A normal phone can not perform this kind of activity.

Answer (score 1):

by using gsm call the feature you want doesn't have any api support. But you can try any of the following

**Case 1:**

when a number key is pressed during call then a dtmf tone is send. try if you can somehow  decode the dtmf tone. As there is no recording option in android during call you can try setting speakerphone on.. ( i haven't tried this, so not sure fully)
For this you can see this [project](https://code.google.com/p/dtmf-decoder/source/checkout)

**Case 2**

Create another channel over network. create server client mechanism to register each number in your server. whenever two calls of two registered users are made send data over network.
you can see a similar apps [thruto](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thrutu.client&hl=en)

Comment: i dont want to use case 2
and case 1 is not possible.
Thanks for giving clarification.